# Transaction enlistment (resource) commit order

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, transactionscope

Is there any way to change commit order of enlistments (resources) of transaction?

I have multiple resources (enlistments) participating in one transaction, A and B, both are valotile and do not support 2PC, resource A is enlisted first, and so commits first, however I need it to enlist first, but commit last (to prevent data loss because i'm moving data from A to B). I can't change code to enlist resource B first.

Currently I'm thinking only on using reflection on transaction to change order in private enlistment list.